# Removing rows dependent on one column Python

Tags: python

I'm working on taking apart a python script piece by piece to get a better understanding of 1.) how python works & 2.) what this particular script does & if I can make it better (i.e. usable by slightly more varied inputs).

Okay so, there is a line in my code that looks like this:

```
thisChrominfo = chrominfo[thisChrom]
```

Where `chrominfo` calls a dictionary set that looks like this:

```
{'chrY': ['chrY', '59373566', '3036303846'], 'chrX': ['chrX', '155270560', '2881033286'], 'chr13': ['chr13', '115169878', '2084766301'], 'chr12': ['chr12', '133851895', '1950914406'], 'chr11': ['chr11', '135006516', '1815907890'], 'chr10': ['chr10', '135534747', '1680373143'], 'chr17': ['chr17', '81195210', '2500171864'], 'chr16': ['chr16', '90354753', '2409817111'], 'chr15': ['chr15', '102531392', '2307285719'], 'chr14': ['chr14', '107349540', '2199936179'], 'chr19': ['chr19', '59128983', '2659444322'], 'chr18': ['chr18', '78077248', '2581367074'], 'chrM': ['chrM', '16571', '3095677412'], 'chr22': ['chr22', '51304566', '2829728720'], 'chr20': ['chr20', '63025520', '2718573305'], 'chr21': ['chr21', '48129895', '2781598825'], 'chr7': ['chr7', '159138663', '1233657027'], 'chr6': ['chr6', '171115067', '1062541960'], 'chr5': ['chr5', '180915260', '881626700'], 'chr4': ['chr4', '191154276', '690472424'], 'chr3': ['chr3', '198022430', '492449994'], 'chr2': ['chr2', '243199373', '249250621'], 'chr1': ['chr1', '249250621', '0'], 'chr9': ['chr9', '141213431', '1539159712'], 'chr8': ['chr8', '146364022', '1392795690']}
```

and thisChrom calls a single column (non-integer) that includes things like this:

```
'*' to `chr4`to `chrY` etc.
```

thisChrom only returns one value at a time, because it relies on a piece higher up in the file that specifies only a single row:

```
for x in INFILE:
    arow = x.rstrip().split("\t")
    thisChrom = arow[2]
    thisChrompos = arow[3]
```

So it's pulling one column from one row.

The whole thing falls apart when values like `'*'` are present in `arow`, because that's not in the `chrominfo` dictionary. At first I thought I should just go ahead and add it to the dictionary, but now I'm thinking it would be easier and better to instead add a line at the top that says something like, `if arow[2] == '*' then delete it, else continue`.

I know it should look something like this:

```
for x in INFILE:
    arow = x.rstrip().split("\t")
    thisChrom = arow[2]
    thisChrompos = arow[3]
    if arow == '*': arow.remove(*)
    else:
        continue
```

but I haven't been able to get the syntax quite right. All of my Python is self & stackoverflow taught, so I appreciate your suggestions and guidance. Sorry if that was an over-explanation of something that is very simple for most experts (I am not an expert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` keyword is somewhat non-obvious. What it does is skip the remaining contents of the loop, and start the next iteration. So, what you wrote will skip the rest of the loop only if `arow` is **not** equal to `'*'`.

Instead of

```
if arow == '*': arow.remove(*)
else:
    continue
# process the row
```

you might simply want to either use a simple `if` condition:

```
if arow != '*':
    # process the row
```

or use `continue` in the way you probably intended:

```
if arow == '*': continue
# process the row
```

See how it works in the opposite way of what you thought? Also, you don't need an `else` in this case because of how the `continue` skips the rest of the loop.

---

If you're familiar with the `break` keyword, it may make more sense as a comparison. The `break` keyword stops the loop entirely - it "breaks" out of it and moves on. The `continue` keyword is simply a "weaker" version of that - it "breaks" out of the current iteration but not all the way out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the explanation too - very helpful :]